# Is there any alternative to file system watcher?

Tags: large-files, filesystemwatcher, web-farm

We are creating a webfarm and used filesystemwatcher to notify changes when some files are uploaded on one of the server.When there are large no of files file system watcher is not working properly.It shows internalbuffersize overflow problem.Is there any solution for this?If not what could be the best alternative for this.We would be very grateful if proper solution is adviced.

Comment: Hello @santosh sir  , internship opportunity xa ra tapaiko company ma?

Answer (score 0):

The buffer does have a limit and though this limit can be increased, it will still exist.

The alternative is to employ a filesystem filter driver that will catch changes right when they happen. The drawback of the filter driver is that you need to install it on the system which handles filesystem requests, i.e. you can't monitor server A for changes made by server B from client system C. You need to install the filter driver on server A for it to track changes made by B.

Our CallbackFilter product offers a pre-created filter driver so that you can write just a user-mode code.